# Vue List Move Transitions Only Work When Reordering, But Not Splicing

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, transition

I have a Vue.js application (tested with both Vue 2 and 3) which displays a list of items in a `transition-group` which has a fade effect and should also be applying a [list move transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions). Anytime items are reordered (i.e an item that was prevously after a another item is moved before it), the move transition is applied, but if an item is removed with `splice` and the others stay in the same order, the move transition doesn't apply and the items after the removed one snap into place immediately. Here's a minimal example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    list: [1, 2, 3]
  }),
  methods: {
    reorder() {
      this.list.unshift(this.list[this.list.length - 1])
        this.list.splice(this.list.length - 1, 1)
    },
    remove() {
        this.list.splice(1, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

li {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.v-enter-active, .v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.v-enter, .v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="reorder">Reorder</button>
  <button @click="remove" :disabled="list.length < 3">Remove Middle Item</button>

  <transition-group tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in list" :key="item">{{ item }}</li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my first answer in stack overflow, sorry in advanced if I'm not that accurate with my answer.

From the [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions) documentation I managed to make it work by adding position absolute to the class .v-leave-active. I also modified the li transition duration to match with the opacity transition timing.

I hope it helped!

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    list: [1, 2, 3]
  }),
  methods: {
    reorder() {
      this.list.unshift(this.list[this.list.length - 1])
        this.list.splice(this.list.length - 1, 1)
    },
    remove() {
        this.list.splice(1, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

li {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.v-enter-active, .v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.v-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}

.v-enter, .v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="reorder">Reorder</button>
  <button @click="remove" :disabled="list.length < 3">Remove Middle Item</button>

  <transition-group tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in list" :key="item">{{ item }}</li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: You save my life